# C# Web API 2 Collect Additional Information About Windows Authenticated User

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api2, windows-authentication

I am working on the beginnings of a Web API web service for an intranet application. We will be requiring Windows Authentication at the IIS level and I can successfully grab the user name from `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`. We store additional information about the user in the application database that I need to grab and add to the request somewhere (or if not the actual request object, somewhere else that can be accessed by Controllers).

My thought is to run the DB query to capture this information as soon as the request has been authenticated and create an `AppUser` object with the additional information I need.

The question is where should this action be performed? A couple things I have seen when searching around but I am not sure the appropriate place - this is my first foray into Web API.

- Global.asax Application_PostAuthenicateRequest - this seems to be more at the application level - not the individual request level
- AuthenticationFilter - this seems to be more focused on custom authentication
- Master Controller - sub class ApiController and create a master controller on which all other controllers inherit - and add some methods into this master controller which do the work

I am sure there may be more than 1 "right" way but looking for some best practices/guidance on the subject.

EDIT

I would also like to be able to use information from the DB (stored in the `AppUser` object) to handle the logic inside of the `[Authorize]` attribute (be that generally authorization, admin roles, etc.).

Comment: How often do you need this AppUser information? Are you making your Web API stateless?

Comment: It will be stateless yes. So it will be needed on every request. Ultimately this will be hit via AJAX on the front end UI. Not fully opposed to stateful but it seems like a lot of extra work and overhead to maintain the state right?

Answer (score 1):

In general your should get this information at the time your actually need them, personally i prefer to have a method or property AppUser on the Base Controller (the master controller) and this method/property will abstract all the details of retrieving the user data from the database, make sure to cache the data once returned from the database in a caching service or even in the memory of the running controller instance, something like the below

```
 public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    private AppUser appUser = null;
    protected AppUser CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            if(appUser==null)
                appUser=LoadUserInfo();
            return appUser;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In this scenario would `AppUser` be accessible inside an `[Authorize]` attribute on a controller/action? One of the data elements brought back from the DB is whether the user is an admin or not and being able to decorate a controller/action with `[Authorize(Role=Admin)]` would be very helpul and having that pull from `AppUser` would be even better.

Comment: Your will most likely need to create custom Authorization Attributes if you want to decorate controllers and actions and define authorization based on our AppUser class.